# C# Linq List<string> takewhile

Tags: c#, linq, list

Please look at following code in Linqpad and tell me why it returns 0 items instead of 1 items.

```
void Main()
{
    string[] strArray = {"apple", "banana", "cherry", "e"};
    List<string> lst = strArray.ToList();

    //count all occurences of variable alphabet "e" in LINQ

    //tip is to get the occurences of letter "e" in each word
    // and then total them together

    var lst2 = lst.TakeWhile(c=>c.Equals("banana")).Select(c=>c);

    Console.WriteLine(lst2);
}
```

The above code does not return 1 item in linqpad as I would expect. Instead it returns 0 items.  The list with 1 item "banana" should return. Why does it not?

Comment: use `Where` instead of takewhile

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems pretty clear to me. Why did you expect it to return 1 item, bearing in mind what the documentation says?

Comment: Why the down vote?  This is a legit question and before reading it I had never looked at TakeWhile.  Thanks for asking user1141419.

Comment: It's take while, not take until.  Maybe you actually want `lst.TakeWhile(c=>c!="banana")`

Comment: @Sam: I downvoted because it at least *appears* to show a lack of research: reading the documentation is all that's required to answer the question. If the OP has actually read the documentation but is still surprised by the result, they should have explained why they expected there to be a single result. Questions which are explained *just* by reading simple documentation aren't useful, IMO. (If the documentation is unclear or complicated, that's a different matter - but I don't believe it's the case here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TakeWhile` will take element as long as the condition is true. In your case it's false at the beginning because it's evaluate `if ("apple" == "banana")` and it's not so the `TakeWhile` stop.

If you put the element "banana" at beginning, it will work.

```
string[] strArray = {"banana", "apple", "cherry", "e"};
```

Plus, you can only write.

```
 var lst2 = lst.TakeWhile(c=>c.Equals("banana"))
```

The select is useless.

Answer (score 13):

Documentation for `TakeWhile`:

> Returns elements from a sequence as long as a specified condition is true.

Since a `List` is ordered, the first item, "apple" does not equal  "banana".  The condition is false and `TakeWhile` exits before it reaches the "banana" item.

You may be looking to use the `Where` method instead

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

Answer (score 4):

@arcyqwerty explained why you're getting your results.  For your expected results, use `Where` in this instance:

```
var lst2 = lst.Where(c=>c.Equals("banana"));
```

Also, no need for `Select(c => c)`, it's redundant.

Comment: Humpf... Beat me by 32 seconds.  Knew I should not  have actually bothered testing it....

Answer (score 2):

Because it is taking *while* the iterated item is a banana, since the first item it arrives to is not a banana, it stops the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This will return 1 item ("banana"):

```
var result = lst.Where(c => c.Equals("banana")).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

As the others pointed out, no need for a `TakeWhile` where a simple `Where` will suffice.

EDIT: From your code comments, it looks like you might be trying to count the occurrences of 'e' in the source list. This will do that for you:

```
var list = new List<string> { "apple", "banana", "cherry", "e" };

var count = list
    .SelectMany(x => x.ToArray()) // flatten into list of chars
    .Where(x => x.Equals('e'))
    .Count();
Console.Write(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

arcyqwerty tell you why.  He left out what you want instead:

```
var lst2 = lst.Where(c=>c.Equals("banana")).Select(c=>c);
```

Comment: `Select(c=>c)` is unnecessary, I think.